# Set a timeout on socket_read

Tags: php, sockets, timeout

I was wondering how can I set a timeout on a `socket_read` call? The first time it calls `socket_read`, it waits till data is sent, and if no data is sent within 5 secs I want to shutdown the connection. Any Help? I already tried `SO_RCVTIMEO` with no luck.

I'm creating a socket with `socket_create()` and listening on it for connections, then when connected I listen for the data and then do something with it. When the timeout hits, I want to run `socket_shutdown()` and then `socket_close()`.

Comment: Please take to the note that Windows Sockets API doesn't work with timeouts less then 500 ms. You can set timeout to much smaller amount of time, but while you will be on Windows platform you should know that this probably will not work as you wanted to. Reference: http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/WW/sampchap/4287d.aspx .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a socket_listen and then I made a manual timeout with time()+2 and a while loop with nonblock set and socket_read() inside. Seems to be working ok. Any alternatives?

UPDATE: I found that setting the socket as nonblocking and then using socket_listen provided the timeout I needed.

Comment: Oooh, you're accepting socket connections with PHP.  That's a bit different. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php  Select will return sockets if there is anything available to be read, otherwise time out with your specified timeout.

Answer (score 27):

this set 5 sec timeout of the socket.

```
socket_set_option($socket,SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>5, "usec"=>0));
```

Comment: after some testing - this appears to be the lifetime of the entire socket - no just the socket_read

Comment: Interesting observation: if you use PHP_NORMAL_READ instead of PHP_BINARY_READ (default) as the third argument to socket_read(), it will ignore the timeout set using socket_set_option() and will block indefinitely until something is sent... (observed with PHP 5.5.9)

Comment: Another interesting observation: It does not work if you remove ` usec` from the array

Comment: does not work reliable, you can't trust it. I have plenty of cases where it hangs for minutes even though timeout of few milliseconds is configured.  
Might depend on TCP flags

Comment: Setting this on the main `$socket` created with `socket_create()` will affect both `socket_accept()` timeout and `socket_read()` timeout. To affect just socket_read() timeout, set this on the second socket name created with `$socket_name = socket_accept()`.

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried [socket_set_option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-option.php) with [SO_RCVTIMEO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-get-option.php)

Timeout value for input operations.

Comment: I tried! I think I found a solution with socket_listen and a manual timeout with time()+2 and a while.

Comment: Brilliant! That solved it for me. I now have a `socket_read()` that times out for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$read_socket = socket_select($read, $write  = NULL, $except = NULL, 10); // 10 - Timeout
if($read_socket === FALSE)
    $this->End();
elseif($read_socket === 0)
    return FALSE;

$pdu_ = socket_read($this->session, 102400);
if($read_socket && !strlen($pdu_))
    $this->End();
```

Comment: An explanation would be helpful.